# VSS-like feature for SMB file shares in Samba4

Tags: samba4, vss

In Samba4, is there any feature like VSS for SMB file shares in Windows Server?

I see that the `Previous Version` tab exists under `Properties` in the context menu on the client side, but I don't know how to turn it on at the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a vfs module: [vfs_shadow_copy2](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_shadow_copy2.8.html). There are different techniques for filesystems supporting snapshots, and for those that don't, with LVM, for example (so far you didn't specify any).